# Python - list index out of range with arrays

Tags: python, indexing

Basically i want to create something that outputs me new created lists.

```
def map(mines, layers):
    mine_distance = []
    mine_sector = []
    for i in range(layers):
        if mines[i][0] != 0 and mines[i][1] != 0:
            mine_distance.append(mine_distance[i][0])
            mine_sector.append(mine_sector[i][1])
    print(mine_distance, mine_sector)

map([[2, 4], [2, 1]], 5)
```

But i get this error:
IndexError: list index out of range

The output should be :
[2, 2]  [4, 1]
Can somebody help me?

Comment: What did you expect this to do - `mine_distance.append(mine_distance[i][0])
            mine_sector.append(mine_sector[i][1])` ?

Comment: To take the first and the second element from the 1st array and add them to mine_distance or mine_sector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it should be corrected as:

```
mine_distance.append(mines[i][0])
mine_sector.append(mines[i][1])
```

Previously you were trying to access (`mine_distance.append(mine_distance[i][0])`, which is empty at this point of time) element of an **empty list**, and hence getting the `IndexOutOfBounds` error.

Another reason for `IndexOutOfBounds` error is the inequality in `len(mines)` and `layers`, You should either pass the `layer` argument = `len(mines)` or you should change the loop as `for i in range(len(mines)):`

Comment: Thank for your answer, but it still gives me the out of range error, even when i change the lines to match yours

Comment: because you are using layers as `5`, though your actual array does not have that many layers

Comment: I shouldnt be using layers yet.. If it does then i guess thats were the problem is..

Comment: That is `logical` error, you must first define to yourself as what this layers variable means to you and write the logic accordingly

Comment: Well layers variable is something i will use later on, at the moment i just need to use the lists that come from mines. In this example they are [[2, 4], [2, 1]]

Comment: The you should edit the `for` loop accordingly, change it to `for i in range(len(mines))`, otherwise you will always get `IndexOutOfBoundsError`